# IronPython vs. Python .NET

Tags: python, .net, ironpython, cpython, python.net

I want to access some .NET assemblies written in C# from Python code.

A little research showed I have two choices:

- [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython) with .NET interface capability/support built-in
- Python with the [Python .NET](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) package

What are the trade-offs between both solutions?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you want to mainly base your code on the .NET framework, I'd highly recommend IronPython vs Python.NET.  IronPython is pretty much native .NET - so it just works great when integrating with other .NET langauges.

Python.NET is good if you want to just integrate one or two components from .NET into a standard python application.

There are notable differences when using IronPython - but most of them are fairly subtle.  Python.NET uses the standard CPython runtime, so [this Wiki page](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=IPy1.0.xCPyDifferences&referringTitle=Home) is a relevant discussion of the differences between the two implementations.  The largest differences occur in the cost of exceptions - so some of the standard python libraries don't perform as well in IronPython due to their implementation.

Comment: IronPython has "lightweight" exceptions now which are much faster. A TryRaiseExcept test from PyBench which performed 60 times slower, now is just 1.6 times slower. WithRaiseExcept is still slow, but 4 times faster than previously. For most other tests, IPy is actually *faster*. [**IronPython 2.7 vs CPython 2.7 performance comparison**](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IP27A1VsCPy27Perf) (complete [list of benchmarks](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IronPython%20Performance)).

Answer (score 30):

While agreeing with the answers given by Reed Copsey and Alex Martelli, I'd like to point out one further difference - the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). While IronPython doesn't have the limitations of the GIL, CPython does - so it would appear that for those applications where the GIL is a bottleneck, say in certain multicore scenarios, IronPython has an advantage over Python.NET.

From the Python.NET documentation:

> **Important Note for embedders:** Python
>   is not free-threaded and uses a global
>   interpreter lock to allow
>   multi-threaded applications to
>   interact safely with the Python
>   interpreter. Much more information
>   about this is available in the Python
>   C API documentation on the
>   `www.python.org` Website.
>
> When embedding Python in a managed
>   application, you have to manage the
>   GIL in just the same way you would
>   when embedding Python in a C or C++
>   application.
>
> Before interacting with any of the
>   objects or APIs provided by the
>   `Python.Runtime` namespace, calling code
>   must have acquired the Python global
>   interpreter lock by calling the
>   `PythonEngine.AcquireLock` method. The
>   only exception to this rule is the
>   `PythonEngine.Initialize` method, which
>   may be called at startup without
>   having acquired the GIL.
>
> When finished using Python APIs,
>   managed code must call a corresponding
>   `PythonEngine.ReleaseLock` to release
>   the GIL and allow other threads to use
>   Python.
>
> The `AcquireLock` and `ReleaseLock`
>   methods are thin wrappers over the
>   unmanaged `PyGILState_Ensure` and
>   `PyGILState_Release` functions from the
>   Python API, and the documentation for
>   those APIs applies to the managed
>   versions.

Another issue is IDE support. CPython probably has better IDE support at present than IronPython - so this may be a factor in the choosing of one over the other.

Comment: The PyDev Eclipse plugin supports CPython, IronPython and Jython.

Comment: @Knut: Right, but that wasn't the situation when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 20):

Most of scientific and numerical Python libraries that rely on CPython C-API (numpy, scipy, matplotlib, pandas, cython, etc.) are working mostly under CPython, so in that case your best bet is pythonnet (other names - Python.NET and Python for .NET).
The same is true for CPython GUI bindings such as WxWidgets, PyQt/PySide, GTK, Kivy, etc., although both pythonnet and IronPython can use WPF and WinForms.

And finally IronPython does not fully support Python 3 yet.

Answer (score 9):

IronPython is ".NET-native" -- so it will be preferable if you want to fully integrate your Python code with .NET all the way; Python.NET works with Classic Python, so it lets you keep your Python code's "arm's length" away from .NET proper.  (Note that with [this code](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/cpython_extensions.shtml) you can actually use extensions written for CPython from your IronPython code, so that's not a discriminating condition any more).

Answer (score 6):

IronPython comes from Microsoft, so I would go with my gut and use that one first since you have to assume it will play nicer with other MSFT technologies.

Comment: i doubt this since its not part of vs20xx

Answer (score 5):

As for 2016.

In my company we used IronPython, but we were not satisfied with performances (mostly memory use - garbage collector was too slow) so we decided to switch to standard Python and integrate it with .Net using Zeroce-s ICE.

Comment: I'm surprised that RPC between different processes was chosen for performance reasons. Most likely CPython + .NET using pythonnet in the same process should be faster than this approach. As for Zeroce ICE note that it is GPL-licensed and so not very suitable for commercial applications.

Comment: An interesting solution, thanks.  As for licensing, there is a commercial option for ICE: https://zeroc.com/licensing

Answer (score 4):

IronPython, currently,  doesn't support Python 3.6 (only 2.7)

from [IronPython 3](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3#ironpython-3) *"Builds of IronPython 3 are not yet provided."*

Comment: They are currently working on v3 but very slowly: https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3

Answer (score 2):

1. Ironpython is like C# in turn it relies on static prebuilt libraries while unlike C# is a dynamic language.
2. Cpython is like C++ like Ironpython is a dynamic language and has access to dynamic libraries which in turn translates to being forced to write everything.
3. Ironpython is faster than C# in certain areas but not faster than Cpython, however you can link Ironpython to any language thus over coming problems but then again you can do the same with Cpython.

A funny, simple and powerful language regardless what you choose!

Answer (score 1):

Iron Python is basically Python 2.7 with integrated .net support it probably will never support Python 3. It loses out on C and Python libraries, however on the twist side has access to .net and can be extended with C#. So if you use C# already then Iron Python is a bonus.

Answer (score -1):

I mainly prefer Python for .NET, because IronPython is compiled as managed code, which can be easily decompiled (what I most hate), but with py2exe or pyinstaller you can compile Python with NET module as an unmanaged application.