# Streamlabs Chatbot: No module named fcntl

Tags: python

I am new at Python and I try to write a script for Streamlabs Chatbot using interprocess communication. The problem is that the chatbot thows an error when I include the following line to the file:

```
import multiprocessing
```

Error message:

```
"No module named fcntl"
```

My operation system is Windows, and I googled that "fcntl" is not available here. However, when I execute the same command from the command line, it works! So I may suggest that the chatbot somehow tries to use Unix-libraries instead of the Windows ones in some cases.
So maybe I have to force the chatbot to use the appropriate libraries, but I don't know how.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422368/fcntl-substitute-on-windows

Comment: Thank you! I watched this thread, but I don't think this is a solution because "multiprocessing" is a standard Python module, so I don't feel I should edit it somehow.

Comment: try to reduce your code to a minimum what shows an error. Of cause ```import multiprocessing``` itself don't emit it. Show the code and full stacktrace of the error

Comment: Well, maybe I'm just a Python newbie:( I was said that the chatbot is implemented with Iron Python and according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855211/can-i-use-all-standard-python-libraries-with-ironpython-or , some standard Python libraries may not work with IronPython. So, maybe this is the source of the error, and this is not a problem at all. Then the .NET libraries may fit perfectly.